# Надо выполнить около 5000 запросов INSERT

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование

Есть задачка при нажатии на кнопку сделать 5000-6000 записей в таблицу. Умею сделать через цикл, но переживаю что загружу сервер такими нажатиями. Читал что ставить запросы в цикл это не правильно. Помогите пожалуйста с каким-то элегантным решением.

Comment: Используйте prepared statements и транзакции.

Comment: варианты: использовать процедуры или фоновые задачи

Comment: Ну и зачем так много записей?

Comment: Задача быстро заполнить базу данных

Comment: Какими данными заполнять?

Comment: О какой базе данных идет речь? Этот объем можно вставить за считанные секунды если использовать COPY в postgres или LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE в mysql

Answer (score 1):

Внутри одного `INSERT` можно вставить несколько строк и послать один запрос вместо нескольких:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2)
VALUES
(123, "a"),
(456, "b")
```

Как конкретно это сделать эффективно и безопасно (чтобы избежать SQL-инъекций) - зависит от используемого языка программирования.

Answer (score 0):

В базах данных можно это делать транзакциями, например:

```
BEGIN
INSERT <...>;
INSERT <...>;
END;
```

Comment: Спасибо, а сервер не зависнет от количества?

Comment: по большому счёту 5К инсёртов это не так много, выполнится примерно за 1-2 секунды, всё зависит от размера таблицы,т.к. при `INSERT` должен проверяться ключ и валидация полей. 
Для того, чтобы БД не проверяла ключ и не проводила валидацию надо почитать документацию на конкретно вашу СУБД

Comment: @Chloroform Добавление 1000 записей через 1000 insert заняло у меня 47 секунд

Comment: @Alex78191, что за БД используете? Такой долгий insert может быть из-за большой таблицы или не правильного конфига БД

Comment: @Chloroform MySQL

Comment: @Alex78191, возможно подойдёт "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" тут про это в комментариях к вопросу писали